# How do I remove segment 1 in my URL AND get the parent URI?

Tags: structure, segments, parents

I have a structured group of pages in a static channel that I would like to display without "static" in the URL and show the parent URI. This is my structure:

```
patients-visitors
---- our-stories
-------- share-your-story
support-groups
---- healing-yoga
```

All of these entries are in a "static" channel. When I roll over the link in the Control Panel, my link look like this:

```
https://www.website.com/static/patient-visitors
---- https://www.website.com/static/our-stories
-------- https://www.website.com/static/share-your-story
https://www.website.com/static/support-groups
---- https://www.website.com/static/healing-yoga
```

However, I want the links to look like this:

```
https://www.website.com/patients-visitors
---- https://www.website.com/patients-visitors/our-stories
-------- https://www.website.com/patients-visitors/our-stories/share-your-story
https://www.website.com/support-groups
---- https://www.website.com/support-groups/healing-yoga
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete answer is a combination of Brandon's instruction, and additional information/details. To remove the first segment, I just needed to remove 'static/' from the Entry URI Format as Brandon instructed.

To get the parent slug in the hierarchy, I added this:

```
{parent.uri}/{slug}
```

However, on first observation of the link after I made this update, the link was still not correct. This is because the queue had not yet gone through an updated all of the links in the DB. I have a ton of entries, and this process took nearly 45 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Edit your section‘s settings (Settings > Sections > [Section Name]), and delete the `static/` from the Entry URI Format.

Comment: I've done this, but I believe that the queue is causing an update bottleneck? I assume that that my structure entries will not take on the new URL until the updating has cleared? When I make that change it triggers 109 queue jobs.

Comment: It was the delay in the queue which caused me to believe that my changes were having no effect. After 45 mins, the queue was cleared and the links are now correct.

Comment: Ah yes, it’s not immediate.